# How to clear the values entered in the textbox by pressing F5 or Refreshing the page? (without using btnReset)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How to clear the values entered in the textbox by pressing F5 or Refreshing the page? (without using btnReset)

I have entered some values in the form as I want to refresh instead submitting the form, but the textbox values are not getting cleared. Any help or suggestions?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Also try disabling ViewState on those controls if they are ASP.NET controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you say i guess that your problem is the browser has remembered your Details and this is an autocomplete feture used in most of the modern browsers.

You can disable it with the `autocomplte` attribute like so :

```
<form method="post" action="something.php" autocomplete="off">

 <input type="text" name="firstName" >
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```